# Multiple nebular dialogs using ng-template

Tags: angular, nebular

Could someone please tell me if its possible to have multiple nbDialog's using ng-template
or would i have to use components?

any help would be great as I have tried all sorts to no avail, and can not see anything on the docs for this.

**myComponent.ts**

```
openQuestions(dialog: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.dialogService.open(dialog, { context: `data to pass to dialog.` })
  }
```

**myTemplate.html**

////////page code goes here//////

```
<ng-template  #dialog let-data let-ref="dialogRef" 
[formGroup]="addDailyCheckEquipment">
<- form to be added here ->
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,

to select the template you want to open you have to add the template ID as an argument when calling the function.

```
<button nbButton status="info" fullWidth (click)="open(TEMPLATE NAME HERE WITHOUT QUOTATION MARKS)">add questions</button>
```